# Hadoop YARN: Failed to launch container

Tags: hadoop

I am getting an out of memory error on datanodes in my Hadoop 2.3.0 cluster when running Hive queries. What settings should I be looking at to prevent the nodemanager from going down?

```
2014-04-29 12:03:33,505 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Failed to launch container.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:932)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.getProviderClass(FactoryFinder.java:112)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:178)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:147)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:265)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2172)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2089)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:838)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTrimmed(Configuration.java:857)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1876)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.createFileSystem(AbstractFileSystem.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.get(AbstractFileSystem.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$2.run(FileContext.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$2.run(FileContext.java:329)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getAbstractFileSystem(FileContext.java:329)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:443)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getLocalFSFileContext(FileContext.java:409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:185)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:79)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
2014-04-29 12:03:56,003 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.yarn.YarnUncaughtExceptionHandler: Thread Thread[Socket Reader #1 for port 8040,5,main] threw an Error.  Shutting down now...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to increase NodeManager's heap memory, Set the following environment variable in the configuration file `yarn-env.sh` in the configuration directory and restart nodemanger.

```
export YARN_NODEMANAGER_HEAPSIZE=2048
```

Default value is 1000. ie 1000MB